# Large menu help adding in another link button

Tags: html, css, megamenu

I was looking at the mega menus on the w3schools website:  (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_mega_menu.asp).

Using the `"try it yourself"`, I was playing around with it, but struggling to see how to add another mega menu or another link button next to the `dropdown` link.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so far here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the code below, might help you:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content .header {
    background: red;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 250px;
}

.column a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.column a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  
  <!-- START FIRST DROPDOWN -->
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">First Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="header">
        <h2>Mega Menu - first dropdown</h2>
      </div>   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 1</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 2</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 3</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- END FIRST DROPDOWN -->
  
  <!-- START SECOND DROPDOWN -->
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Second Dropdown
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="header">
        <h2>Mega Menu - second dropdown</h2>
      </div>   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 1</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 2</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <h3>Category 3</h3>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <!-- END SECOND DROPDOWN -->
</div>
```

Comment: thanks this works - i thought i tried this but works now! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The code which gives you the megamenu is the following:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
  </div>   
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <h3>Category 1</h3>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h3>Category 2</h3>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h3>Category 3</h3>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Please try to add some code to your question next time. It will be easier and quicker to analyze.

Regards

Comment: Sorry I am using the code and preview window on the site but adding another link after the dropdown link doesn't seem to work? So at present it says HOME | NEWS | DROPDOWN and I was trying to add another link after the dropdown link so it shows the following: HOME | NEWS | DROPDOWN | LINK2